# Geofence exit notification is being triggered while device hasn't entered

Tags: android, location, geofencing

I have integrated Geofences in my application. I have set radius as 100m in India  added entry and exit transition types. I used fake location app to set my location in USA to begin with and never even entered my geofence in India, however I am getting an exit.

I thought exit transition is only triggered when you entered first and then exited the Geofence. I couldn't find any proper definition for Geofence Exit.

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are building `GeofencingRequest` object, you have to give initial trigger which you want to catch. See the sample code below.

```
private fun getGeofencingRequest(): GeofencingRequest {
    return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER) //This is initial action which you want to catch first
        addGeofences(geofenceList)
    }.build()
}
```

May be, in `setInitialTrigger()` method you have entered `GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT`. So, that you are getting exit trigger at start.

**Note**:- Above sample code will trigger enter event if you are already inside your geofence. If you don't want to get any initial trigger, you should use `NO_INITIAL_TRIGGER`.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Now i understand why, I can also do  ```.setTransitionTypes(
                    com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        | com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT
                ``` to catch entering and exit after initial trigger

Comment: @Mysterious_android yes, absolutely. Keep it up.